# Validate a userform textbox with decimal format

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I am trying to validate a TextBox in a Userform. The user can only enter in the format of xx.x.

For example 34.5 is acceptable.
If the user enters 3.4 a MsgBox is shown and the user is asked to enter again.

My problem is the MsgBox is showing when the user enters the correct format (for example 45.6).

I am using the BeforeUpdate function for the TextBox.

```vb
Private Sub TextBox2_BeforeUpdate(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
my_format = Format("00.0")
If Not my_format Then
    MsgBox " xx.x is the required format.", vbCritical
    
    Cancel = True

End If
End Sub
```

I think the problem is on the line:  `If Not my_format Then ....`

I am trying to say:
If TextBox.Value is not equal to my_format show a msg.

Comment: How about telling the user to input just 3 numbers without any sign ? Then in the `Private Sub TextBox1_Change()`, have this line `If Len(TextBox1.Value) = 3 And Mid(TextBox1.Value, 3, 1) <> "." Then TextBox1.Value = Left(TextBox1.Value, 2) & "." & Right(TextBox1.Value, 1)` to display "xx.x" in the textbox. Please note, the code is not error checking if the user type a letter, so if the user type abc, it will show ab.c

Answer (score 1):

Please, use this updated code:

```
Private Sub TextBox2_BeforeUpdate(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    Dim my_format As String: my_format = "##.#"
    If Not TextBox2.Value Like my_format Then
        MsgBox " xx.x is the required format.", vbCritical
        Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

You need to check **the Text Box value** against the format. The format itself does not have too much meaning in the necessary circumstances...